# Validation In rails 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-2

I have Model Called Student In the student table i am storing student_name, phone number also i stored other model id class i need to check the for create a student record all these 3 values are unique for creating the new record.

Please help me in validating this in rails 2.Also i tried the below validation its validating only two value batch_id and student_name. Along with this I also need to validate phone number

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base>
     validates_uniqueness_of :first_name, :scope => [:phone1, :batch_id]
end
```

Comment: I'm sorry what was the question? Please edit your post, so that it's clear what you are asking.

Comment: I need if same data matches in the 3 columns of same table with same id in a tables should give an error

Comment: thanks for asking i got the solution to my question

Comment: Great! If you've found a solution, please post an answer to your question

Comment: I used this method in my model                                                                                                               validate :is_valid_true

Answer (score 0):

In a model i used the following code to validate

```
module StudentModel                                                                                  validate :is_valid_true                                                                                                 private
def is_valid_true
  @batch = Batch.find(self.batch_id)
  @batch.students.each do |s|
    if ((s.full_name==self.full_name)&&(s.phone2==self.phone2))
      errors.add_to_base("Student with same Name and Mobile number is already Present in the Batch" )
      break
    end
  end
end                                                                                                                         end
end
```

Comment: When i used this to validate i am getting another error while editing the student form its giving the same error for the same student if we have only one data with the same entries any one can give solution for this.